# How to bind Thymeleaf th:field with java 8 LocalDate

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using **spring boot**(2.0.3) along with **Thymeleaf**(3).  I have an issue with trying to bind the **th:field** with **LocalDate**(java 8).  My issue is complicated because the date input is separated by individual fields of day, month and year.

`<input th:field="*{date.day}" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
 <input th:field="*{date.month}" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
 <input th:field="*{date.year}" type="number">`

All is ok with displaying the localDate through **temporals**(thymeleaf-extras-java8time) but its the binding to the field is an issue.

Comment: Do you really want to use binding here? You can go with Xanlotun's answer or just send "unbinded" name-vakue pairs with the form and create your date-object in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it but the LocalDate type has no setters for the day, month and year. Most likely you cannot "collect" the LocalDate object like this. You'll have to create an intermediate object with setters and getters for the day, month and year. Something like LocalDateFields. You'll get this object in the web method and convert it into the LocalDate object.